# MySQL: How do i perform a query on an existing recordset?

Tags: mysql, select

I'd like to perform a `SELECT` query on an existing recordset, for example:

```
query1 = 'Select * from products where onSale = 1'
```

and then

```
query2 = 'Select * from recordset1 where ....'
```

where `recordset1` is the number of rows that `query1` returned.
Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is just in MySQL then you can do

SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM products WHERE onsale =1) AS OnSaleProducts

To use your example,

SELECT distinct colorid from 
(SELECT * FROM product, collectionItems where collectionItems.CollectionID = '6' and collectionItems.ProductID = product.barcode) As 1stResults
where typeid = '".$_SESSION['typeid']."' and stoneid = '".$_SESSION['stoneid']."' 
order by colorid asc;

If you don't want to run the first query again, consider using a temporary table to store the results, and then querying from that, as if it was a normal table.

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE column1 = (SELECT column1 FROM t2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, you could populate temporary table.

For example:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table SELECT * FROM products WHERE onsale = 1
```

You wrote:
*where recordset1 is the number of rows that query1 returned. Any suggestions? Thanks!*

The number of rows can be stored in a variable, in this case you don't need resault set.

Comment: I meant the recordset, not the number itself... sorry